# passing a variable by ref in matlab

Tags: matlab

Can I pass a variable by ref to a function in Matlab?

I want to do something such as this:

```
  function change(x)
      x=x+1;
  end
```

and call it like this:

```
  x=1;
  change(x)
  % x should be 2 now.
```

Comment: Of course you can do that. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Saturisk: No you can't.  Have *you* tried it?  ;)

Comment: Yes I tried it and it did not work!

Comment: Well, it's not as easy as he is proclaiming, you create your function as a .m file. Sorry.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152-can-matlab-pass-by-reference

Comment: @Cheery: That answer sadly misses the point I make in mine that "the handle numeric value is passed by value, so you can't substitute a different object" (it does say the handle is copied, but it doesn't explain the importance, and the "subtlety" mentioned is the delayed copy of large matrices, not the difference between passing a handle by value and true pass by reference)

Answer (score 3):

The usual style for doing this is to have the same name appear in both the input and output parameter lists:

```
function [x] = change(x)
  x=x+1;
end

x = 1;
x = change(x);
% now 2
```

For example, the standard function [`setfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html) works this way.

In addition, handle objects (e.g. graphic handles) are effectively passed by reference -- the handle numeric value is passed by value, so you can't substitute a different object, but any changes made to the handle object in the function will be visible to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not describe your usecase I cannot estimate whether it is worth to define your own handle class but there are situations where you may benefit from the object oriented way.

Your basic example would look something like this:

Define your handle class in a separate file called `cnt.m` (make sure you inherit from the `handle` class):

```
classdef cnt < handle    

    properties (SetAccess = private)
        % a private member variable.
        c = 0;
    end

    methods
        function h = cnt(c_init)
            % CNT    constructs a cnt handle
            %    CNT() 
            %    CNT(INIT)
            if nargin > 0
                h.c = c_init;
            end
        end 

        function change(h)
            % CHANGE    increment by one
            h.c = h.c+1
        end        
    end

end
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
x = cnt();
x.change();
```

and you can also do something like this:

```
function change2(cnt_obj)
cnt_obj.change()
```

and call this function then like so:

```
change2(x)
```

which will then do what you are asking for.

The later is the reason why you should inherit from `handle`. If you create an ordinary `value class` the call to `change2` would create a copy of the actual input object.

**Please note** that for the simple use case you describe doing something like this is **STUPID OVERHEAD**. Use this only in case you have good reason to.

Comment: Thanks, but in my use case, X was changed and not one of its fields. In your solution, h.c was changed not h. Assume that h has several fields and I want to read it from a file. I am looking for a way to do this without manually changing the fields

Comment: probably you should edit your question and explain also the why not only the what. I still don't get it ...